# prepositions for water, river or sea

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Suppose the part pointed out by red ellipse is the surface of the water.

I guess I can call the part pointed out by blue square "**above**" the water.

[image]

I can also call the part pointed out by red square "**under**" the water. Is it grammatical and idiomatic to say this part "**beneath**", "**below**" or "**underneath**" the water?

How about the surface of water?

> "**above**" the surface of water
>
> "**under**" the surface of water
>
> "**underneath**" the surface of water
>
> "**beneath**" the surface of water
>
> "**below**" the surface of water

What prepositions could be used to describe the position relevant to water?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- "**underneath**" means under or right under something or extending down under something. It can be a preposition or an adverb, in some cases even a noun.
- "**beneath**" is a commoly a more *formal* word for *underneath* and may as well mean lower in relation to something, in our case "*the surface of water*". It can also be a preposition or an adverb.
- "**below**" means under something or in the depth of something, extending underneath. It can also be a preposition or an adverb.

As for the difference between *underwater* and *under water*:

- "**underwater**" is mostly an adjective, but is sometimes used as an adverb. It refers to something intended to be used under water.
- "**under water**" is a prepositional phrase that means anywhere below the surface of water, covered in water.

For the red square we can say:

> They are below or underneath (if we are in the boat). Or they are beneath the surface of water. They are under water.

Comment: Don't hurry accepting somebody's answer when it's the solely one there is.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder, you are a great contributor. "if we are in the boat", does that mean, we are those guys in that boat, we could use "**below**" or "**underneath**" to describe the guys under water, right?

Comment: @WXJ96163 Absolutely.

Comment: Thanks for you kindness. All "below, underneath, beneath" could be used with "the surface of water", right? "**Under**" could only be used with "water". Is my understanding right?