# Is it idiomatic to say "could only be used"?

Tags: word-usage, idioms

In my another post ([What prepositions could be used to describe the position relevant to water?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239958/109190)) I said

> "Under" could only be used with "water".

I meant that other prepositions, such as "below, underneath, beneath", could not be used with "water".

Does the quotation clearly convey what I was trying to say?

Is it idiomatic to use that expression?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No, it does not quite get the meaning you want.

> "Under" could only be used with "water."

The way you have your sentence means that there is a limitation of the word "under." That is, the only place you could use "under" would be with "water." That is, you are saying you can't use "under penalty of law" or "under duress" or "under budget."

You might try this.

> Only "under" could be used with "water."

Or possibly this.

> Of the prepositions "below," "under," and "beneath," only "under" could be used with "water."

However, this statement is not really true. It is quite reasonable to say "beneath water" or "below water."

Comment: Yep, you've pretty much written exactly what I was going to write. Have an upvote

Comment: While it's _reasonable_ to say "beneath water" or "below water," I don't think I have ever heard or seen either until just now. I would not consider those phrases to be idiomatic; if I heard either of them I'd certainly do a double-take.

Comment: Heh. They sure appears in movie titles.  https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3517230/ https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11156108/

Comment: Or UNDP Goal 14: "Life below water." https://www.undp.org/content/undp/en/home/sustainable-development-goals/goal-14-life-below-water.html

Comment: @JakeRobb [Let's see what others have to say about this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/527434/beneath-water-below-water). (Feel free to “own” the quotation or not, as you wish.)

Comment: Also, it should be "can', rather than "could".

Comment: @Acccumulation  Could: Has the potential if so inclined. Can: Has the potential regardless of intention.  Either is acceptable here.

Comment: _underwater_ has the idiomatic quality of meaning "completely submerged in water" or "under [the surface of the] water", whereas "beneath water" or "below water" conjure the image someone somehow below/beneath a body of water, but not actually _in_ the water

Comment: It'd be good to note that in and of itself, "[noun] could only be used with [noun]" is a perfectly valid and idiomatic construction; the problem in the instant case is that it doesn't mean what the OP wants it to mean.

Comment: Also, I think what the OP is trying to say is that of "belowwater", "beneathwater", and "underwater", only "underwater" is an actual word.

Comment: @Martha  The OP explicitly mentions prepositions.

Comment: @MikeS  Sure. Coral is then below water, since it sits on the bottom.

Comment: @Martha I think using "instant" in that way outside of legal contexts could be confusing.