# In what ways, a person could be considered as getting **over** the river?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, prepositions

I am a bit confused about the usage of "across/over" involving river.

**Note**: I am not confusing **across** with **over** in general. For instance, I am pretty sure that both those prepositions could be used in the following situation.

> We drove **across/over** the bridge.

When talking about bridge, we would say "a bridge across/over the river". Both prepositions could be used to describe a bridge.

My another post gives lots of means of crossing the river. No matter which way I choose, my action/movement is getting **across** the river.

Is it reasonable to say someone is getting **over** a river? In particular, jump over a river in a car?

[image]

How about a human cannonball?

I am sure it definitely reasonable to use **over** when I in a helicopter.

[image]

I've also posted another question ([Does bridge actually refer to the part on which pedestrians and vehicles move on in everyday English?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239938/109190)) to make sure my understanding about the bridge is right.

Comment: Googling 'over the river', I found many references to an American children's song "Over the River and into the Woods".

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/61836/a-bridge-over-the-river-vs-a-bridge-across-the-river/61838#61838

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. Did you notice that I left comment there about 10 hours ago :)

Comment: Well, that explains pretty convincingly that 'over the river' is acceptable!

Comment: @KateBunting Yes. I got that. That post is discussing the bridge, and my OP is focussing on human being. In what ways, a person could be considered as get **over** the river. Obviously, by swimming does not count, right?